# Not able to create super user with Django manage.py

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-admin, django-1.8

Trying to create a super user for my database:

```
manage.py createsuperuser
```

Getting a sad recursive message:

*Superuser creation skipped due to not running in a TTY. You can run `manage.py createsuperuser` in your project to create one manually.*

Seriously Django? Seriously?

The only information I found for this was the one listed above but it didn't work:
[Unable to create superuser in django due to not working in TTY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26980003/unable-to-create-superuser-in-django-due-to-not-working-in-tty)

And this other one here, which is basically the same:
[Can't Create Super User Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14059573/cant-create-super-user-django)

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment? What kind? Are you running this from the command line inside your virtualenv, or some other way like in an IDE?

Comment: @YPCrumble  Running this from both PyCharm and plain terminal, no virtual environment

Comment: You get the same error in both?

Comment: @YPCrumble exactly the same message

Comment: For me on macOS, I needed to enable the Run Configuration option "Emulate terminal in output console". Fixed the problem in PyCharm 2019.1.3.

Comment: Same here on Windows 10, Pycharm 2019.2

Answer (score 171, accepted):

If you run

```
$ python manage.py createsuperuser
Superuser creation skipped due to not running in a TTY. You can run manage.py createsuperuser in your project to create one manually.
```

from **Git Bash** and face the above error message try to append `winpty` i.e. for example:

```
$ winpty python manage.py createsuperuser
Username (leave blank to use '...'):
```

To be able to run `python` commands as usual on windows as well what I normally do is appending an alias line to the `~/.profile` file i.e.

```
 MINGW64 ~$ cat ~/.profile
 alias python='winpty python'
```

After doing so, either source the `~/.profile` file or simply restart the terminal and the initial command `python manage.py createsuperuser` should work as expected!

Comment: this also works through docker if you run `winpty docker-compose run python manage.py createsuperuser`

Comment: Could you explain what `winpty` is and does?

Comment: When I tried run above command it gives "No module named 'fcntl' " error. But fcntl is not available for windows. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 17):

In virtualenv, for creating super-user for Django project related to git-bash use the command:

```
winpty python manage.py createsuperuser.
```

Comment: For more information refer here :

$ winpty python manage.py createsuperuser
//It should work by just appending 'winpty' before the command

Source
https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/whatever/Superuser+creation+skipped+due+to+not+running+in+a+TTY.+You+can+run+%60manage.py+createsuperuser%60+in+your+project+to+create+one+manually.

Answer (score 15):

I had same problem when trying to create superuser in the docker container with command:
`sudo docker exec -i <container_name> sh`. Adding option -t solved the problem:

`sudo docker exec -it <container_name> sh`

Answer (score 8):

**Since [Django 3.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-createsuperuser) you can create a superuser without TTY in two ways**

**Way 1**: Pass values and secrets as ENV in the command line

```
    DJANGO_SUPERUSER_USERNAME=admin2 DJANGO_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD=psw \
    python manage.py createsuperuser --email=admin@admin.com --noinput
```

**Way 2**: set DJANGO_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD as the environment variable

```
# .admin.env
DJANGO_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD=psw

# bash
source '.admin.env' && python manage.py createsuperuser --username=admin --email=admin@admin.com --noinput
```

**The output should say**: `Superuser created successfully.`

Answer (score 4):

To create an admin username and password, you must first use the command:

**python manage.py migrate**

Then after use the command:

**python manage.py createsuperuser**

Once these steps are complete, the program will ask you to enter:

- username
- email
- password

With the password, it will not show as you are typing so it will appear as though you are not typing, but ignore it as it will ask you to renter the password.
When you complete these steps, use the command:

**python manage.py runserver**

In the browser add "/admin", which will take you to the admin site, and then type in your new username and password.

Answer (score 1):

Check your **docker-compose.yml** file and make sure your django application is labeled by **web** under services.

Answer (score 0):

I tried creating superuser from Stash [ App: Pythonista on iOS ]

[ Make sure migrations are already made ]

```
$ django-admin createsuperuser
```

Answer (score -3):

I figured out how to do so. What I did was I went to VIEWS.py. Next, I imported the module `os`. Then I created a function called `createSuperUser(request):`. Then, I then created a variable called `admin` and set it equal to `os.system("python manage.py createsuperuser")`. Then after that, return `admin`. Finally, I restarted the Django site, then it will prompt you in the terminal.

```
import os

def createSuperUser(request):
    admin = os.system("python manage.py createsuperuser")
    return
```