# Superuser creation skipped due to not running TTY Django. Babun Shell

Tags: python, django, babun

So I have been trying to create a superuser for a application in Django on Babun Shell.

I am getting the following error time and time again:

```
Superuser creation skipped due to not running in a TTY. You can run `manage.py createsuperuser` in your project to create one manually
```

I have tired :

```
winpty python manage.py createsuperuser
```

this gave me the following result:

```
stdin is not a tty
```

Could someone explain to me where I am going wrong and what am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32532900/not-able-to-create-super-user-with-django-manage-py"

Comment: I tried the solution there. It isn't working