# Unable to create super user in django on my online server

Tags: django

Inside the cpanel -> python app i have tried several time to create super user. when I tried to execute this commad inside Execute python script

> manage.py createsuperuser
> then it will return this error

```
Superuser creation skipped due to not running in a TTY. You can run `manage.py createsuperuser` in your project to create one manually.
```

How to solve this problem, or any manuall solution, i found several solution but all the solution for local server.

Comment: Maybe this could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32532900/not-able-to-create-super-user-with-django-manage-py

Comment: this command not works

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between creating superuser on local server and production server. You have to do next:

1. Enter your server via ssh.
2. Go to your project root folder (with manage.py file)
3. Type python manage.py createsuperuser (use your virtual environment or system interpreter, depends on).